# Is ∃x(P(x)→Q(x))≡(∃xP(x)→∃xQ(x))? not the whole proof just first part how it turn to be True.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

∃x(P(x)→Q(x))
For example, the domain could be all positive integers and P(x)=x≤10. To be complete, let's assume Q(x)=x≤−10.

In previous question,it was written that ∃x(P(x)→Q(x)) is true but i have doubt
according to above assumption that there are some number less that 10 that are postive so P(x) is true and Q(x) is false.then it should be false how it is being told as true.I can relate when we ∃x¬P(x)∨∃xQ(x)∃x¬P(x)∨∃xQ(x)  using distributive properties of ∃∃ over ∨∨. perform this but I want to understand without distributive properties.

Comment: The text of the question is totally unintelligible, in contrast to the title, that sound quite simple : "Is it true that $∃x(P(x)→Q(x)) \equiv (∃xP(x)→∃xQ(x))$ ?".

Comment: actually same question is already being asked so I was worried that it will be considered as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement "$\exists x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$" means that, for **some** $x$, if $P(x)$ then $Q(x)$. In the example you give - where the domain is $\mathbb{N}$, $P=\{0, 1, . . . , 10\}$, and $Q=\emptyset$,  we can take this $x$ to be, say, $1701240987$: since $P$ doesn't hold of this $x$, the statement "$P(x)\implies Q(x)$" is true *for this particular $x$*. This means the sentence "$\exists x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$" is true in the structure you describe.

On the other hand, the statement "$\exists xP(x)\implies \exists xQ(x)$" is **not** true in that structure: there *is* an $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds, but there is *not* any $x$ such that $Q(x)$ holds. So the two sentences are not equivalent.

It looks like you've assumed that "$\exists$" distributes over "$\implies$." This is **not** true.

EDIT: Keep in mind that $\implies$ is weird: remember "$a\implies b$" is equivalent to (and, depending what system you're using, shorthand for) "$b\vee\neg a$". The two clauses are treated very differently. A good exercise: find all truth-functionals $\{True, False\}^2\rightarrow \{True, False\}$ which distribute over $\implies$.

---

*Exercise*: Does "$\exists$" distribute over "$\vee$"? Over "$\wedge$"? What about "$\forall$"?

**Note** that there are two senses in which we can talk about distribution of logical operators, and it's important to keep them distinct: we can have *full* distribution, e.g. "$a\vee(b\wedge c)$" is equivalent to "$(a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c)$", or *one-way* distribution, e.g. "$\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$" implies - but may not be equivalent to - "$(\exists xP(x))\wedge(\exists xQ(x))$." Above, I'm talking about the former (stronger) version of distribution.

Comment: So I want to clear my understanding if P is also set of natural number that ∃x(P(x)⟹Q(x)) would be false.Am I right and for ∃xP(x)⟹∃xQ(x) this don't we take same example like say as we have taken x=1701240987 then this is true.

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment, but I think the answer is: in "$\exists xP(x)\implies \exists xQ(x)$," the two $x$s can be different.